# Bootstrap Tabs not Activating Correctly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, html-lists

I'm trying to get my nav tabs to work properly. The ul part is updating correctly to active whenever I click on different tabs, but the `<div class="tab-content">` doesn't update correctly. It just always displays the 1 part.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li data-toggle="tab" class="active"><a href="#1">1</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#2">2</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#3">3</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#4">4</a>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="1">
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="2">
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="3">
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="4">
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also here are the scripts I'm using:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've done this before on a different webpage and it is working fine. For some reason it's not working here. Thank you!

EDIT: I feel like I should mention I have tried with and without the bootstrap.js file and it doesn't work. I know I only need the bootstrap.min.js file but I thought I'd try both to see what happens.

Comment: You should add bootstrap.js only once. Either min file or regular js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data-toggle` should be in right place.

Correct way:-

```html
<li class="active">
      <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">1</a>
</li>
```

Anyway the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15735/) is here.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help to solve your issue.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#4" data-toggle="tab">4</a>
</li></ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="1">
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="2">
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="3">
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="4">
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without using  data-toggle="tab" it will not active your tab-pane so you need that attribute in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

I too face an same problem when working in safari,
Please try it in chrome.

use the script in below mentioned link.

```
<div><ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
```

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Tab content 1</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Tab content 2</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Tab content 3</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Tab content 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs&stacked=h)